# Mobile Friendly Site with centered text in img in div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I need to create a responsive layout, wherein basically I have an image in  center of screen, and text centered in the image.
I'm not sure how exactly to center all these things properly. I tried making the image a background-image in a div, but couldn't center it while making sure it'd grow/shrink as a screen did.
Now I'm not sure how to make it all very contained, without overflowing, and without setting a px size (which a lot of the help articles I've found specify).

This is my idea:

[image: basic idea]

On my website at the moment I've made part of it work and it looks like this:

[image: result]

Except I need it also to be centered vertically and the span is as wide as the screen rather than as wide as the image.

https://jsfiddle.net/zb50azjx/

HTML:

```
<div class="news">
<div><img src="http://m.elysiumrpg.com/images/newstitle.png"/><span>News Title</span></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.news {
    color: #191919;
    font-size: 15pt;
}

.news div img {
    z-index: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.news div span {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    text-align:center;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into using bootstrap ?

Comment: I've heard of it, I think... Googling and will try out now, thanks!

Comment: yes, please check it out, it is what industry uses as standard practice, for building for different devices

Answer (score 0):

```css
.news {
 color: #191919;
 font-size: 15pt;
  display:inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.news div img {
 z-index: 0;a
  width: 100%;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
}

.news div span {
 z-index: 1;
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
   transform: translateY(-50%);
   top: 50%;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="news">
<div><img src="http://m.elysiumrpg.com/images/newstitle.png"/><span>News Title</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: hm, implementing it on the actual website made the title go way down into the middle of the whole document height, and made the image width equal to the screen width when I need it to stay smaller than that?

Comment: have you added position relative to .news element

Comment: Yeah I copied out your sample exactly

Comment: it is, I didn't link it because it wouldn't have stayed accurate for long while I'm experimenting, but: http://m.elysiumrpg.com/

I'm working on the image part directly beneath the header that says News, leaving the below text for when I figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

you can make div within news as position relative and span as position:absolute and set top:40% and left:40% this would give you the text centered within the image

```css
.news {
  color: #191919;
  font-size: 15pt;
}
div.content {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.news div span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 40%;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="news">
  <div class="content">
    <img src="http://m.elysiumrpg.com/images/newstitle.png" /><span>News Title</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: But for dynamic content we need to adjust that 40% #Geeky

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on what text you want centered on the image but see if this is what you are after:
http://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/gLEGqb

Using a background image with CSS of `background-size:contain;` can be really useful sometimes, because it will scale the image well to fit the size of the div

I've simplified your HTML and CSS quite a bit.

Good luck

**HTML**

```
<div class="news">News Title </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.news {
    color: #191919;
    font-size: 15pt;
  background:url('http://m.elysiumrpg.com/images/newstitle.png') ;
  background-size:contain;
  text-align:center;
  padding:20px 0;
}
```